# How to merge 2 rows into 1 row pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this for the 1st few indexes:

[image]

But however as i scrolled down to look at the other indexes, i realise that some ***tax_type*** data were split into ***Individual Income Tax*** and ***Corporate Income Tax***:

[image]

What i wanted to do is to combine the rows that are seperated into individual income tax and corporate income tax and rename them into ***Individual and Corporate Income Tax***, and in the process, sum up the ***no_of_cases*** and ***tax_and_penalty_arising*** int they carry, together.

Can Anyone advice me on how to do it?

Here is my current source code that i have yet to complete(in fact i have no idea how to begin with):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import the csv file
dataname = 'Datasets\\tax-and-penalty-arising-from-audits-by-tax-type.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(dataname)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by dictionary and then aggregate `sum`:

```
d = {'Corporate Income Tax':'Individual and Corporate Income Tax',
     'Individual Income Tax':'Individual and Corporate Income Tax'}
df = df.groupby(['financial_year',df['tax_type'].replace(d)]).sum().reset_index()
```